# Are "to flee from" and "to run away from" interchangeable?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

The verb "to flee" means "to run away" but are they interchangeable in every aspect? I'm kind of confused which one to use. It seems to me that the use of the verb flee could be more elaborate when written and "run away" would be more use in an informal discussion.

In which context one is more suitable than the other?

Comment: 'He ran away from home' sounds far more natural (as an expression!) than 'He fled from home'. 'Flee' carries a great sense of urgency, more than 'run away [from]'.

Comment: No, they aren’t interchangeable: they are not the same length, nor the same number of words, nor most importantly in the same register.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Is the preposition after "flee" optional or is there a rule ?

Comment: @Luis, You could just say 'He fled.' So yes, it is optional.

Comment: @Luis More relevantly, you could say 'He fled the scene of the accident' as an alternative to 'He fled from the scene of the accident', with little change in meaning. _Flee_ can be used both transitively and intransitively; some other verbs behave similarly (eg The cat brushed / brushed against my leg). This does not mean the usages are totally interchangeable – but this may be a matter of preference. I'd be happier with 'fled the wrath to come', 'fled the country' and 'fled from the nursery' than 'fled the nursery', but the internet says that others seem quite happy with 'fled the nursery'.

Comment: @Edwin Re. “the cat brushed my leg”—that just makes me think you've got very hairy legs, and a very dextrous and fashion-aware cat!

Comment: @Janus: Just in case you're serious: **brush** ... v.tr.

3. To touch lightly in passing; graze against. [AHD] Collins Cobuild give a list where V + PP and V + DO are virtually interchangeable. 'France fought against England' = 'France fought England' (and may = 'France fought with England').

Comment: @Edwin Half-serious. I understand what it's supposed to mean, of course, but only because what I initially understand it as makes no sense. “She brushed his shoulder as she passed him in the corridor” is perfectly fine to me (any association to hallway beauty parlours is fleeting at most), but “The cat brushed my leg” is somehow much less willing to right itself into that meaning when I see/hear it.

Comment: No qualms with it here. The contrasting senses are far more obvious in 'Dressed in her finest attire, the Queen swept down the grand staircase and under the chairs in the hall'. [The Two Ronnies;mangled no doubt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To flee* would not be appropriate to substitute in the idiom *running away from your problems*.  *To run away* could be used in place of *to flee* in most cases, but *to flee* coneys a sense of immediate, tangible danger that *to run away* does not.  For example, fleeing the scene of the crime is more powerful than running away from the scene of the crime.

Comment: Of course you can use _flee_ metaphorically. Anything can be used metaphorically.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇, you're right, of course. I've edited it to say it doesn't work in that particular metaphor. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I still feel that you're making a false distinction here. Why can't I flee from my problems? Doesn't that convey that my problems constitute immediate, tangible danger, or that I think they do, or that whoever describes my flight wants to connote that they do?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇, as Henry74 pointed out, I think the use of "flee" carry more the idea of escaping an immediate threat.

Comment: I suppose there could be examples of problems one might *flee from*, but *running away from your problems* is a common idiom that implies you are short-sightedly avoiding your problems rather than facing them.  Using flee here would not just add immediacy but also lose the other implications specific to that idiom.  I'm changing *metaphor* to *idiom* in the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Oh, and here's the ngram. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flee+from+your+problems%2C+run+away+from+your+problems&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crun%20away%20from%20your%20problems%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

While they may be similar I don't think you can use them in every context.

> Run - pass or cause to pass quickly or smoothly in a particular direction.
>
> Run - move about in a hurried and hectic way.

There are multiple definitions for the word Ran but from my research these two most closely relate to flee. Also flee has more of a negative connotation to it for example.

> Flee - run away from a place or situation of danger.
>
> Flee - run away from (someone or something).
>
> "I can't wait to run away and start my life in Europe!"
>
> "I cant wait to flee and start my life in Europe!"

The second one doesn't sound right, even though both would need to defined more clearly with context clues, you can assume what the person who spoke the first sentence meant easier than the second.

Answer (score 0):

As Henry74 and dom176 mentioned, it's not always interchangeable. Consider this illustrative example:

The outfielder misjudged the ball's path, and too late he realized he was not running towards the ball, he was running away from it.

Here "running away" just indicates he was moving in the opposite direction, rather than "he was fleeing from it" would indicate a desire to escape.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site; to lend support to answers already given, please vote rather than commenting from the Your Answer box. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score -1):

Both are the same, the difference is that to run away is not such formal as flee is, run away is a phrasal verb and it sounds more natural.